# How can I get RGB array from img?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the RGB array of img using canvas like this:

**Teplate**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <img id="face" src="./220px-Leonhard_Euler.jpg" />
    <canvas
      id="face2"
      width="112"
      height="112"
      style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"
    ></canvas>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
const img = document.getElementById("face");
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

const canvas = document.getElementById("face2");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

let pix = context.getImageData(0, 0, 112, 112).data;
pix = Array.from(pix);

const pix2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < pix.length; i += 4) {
  pix2.push(pix[i + 0]);
  pix2.push(pix[i + 1]);
  pix2.push(pix[i + 2]);
}

const imgData = context.createImageData(112, 112);

for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = pix2[i + 0];
  imgData.data[i + 1] = pix2[i + 1];
  imgData.data[i + 2] = pix2[i + 2];
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}

context.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);
```

As you can see in the first part of the code I try to extract the 4d array of the image RGBA, and try to remove the alpha channel.

After that, I tried to set again the image with a default alpha channel like 255 only to check that I got the RGB data only.

But I got the following image:

[image]

The input image is 112x112 and the canvas is 112x112, any idea about why I could get only the RGB of the img?

**EDIT2**

The @tracktor response worked but I still get error with another image like this:

[image]

Same code the only difference is that I load this image using http://localhost:8080/face.jpg instead of crossorigin.

Thanks

Comment: Setting alpha channel bytes in `pix` may be easier Also suggest checking the canvas is not tainted and pixel values are actually accessible.

Comment: I want to remove alpha pixel of the array, and I want to check that I remove the correct pixels painting again inside another canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTMLImageElement   `crossorigin` attribute

Put a `crossorigin` attribute on the `img` tag in HTML to ensure the browser *requests* the image with headers for a CORS operation, such as

> ```
>    Origin: http://localhost
>    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
>    Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
> ```

In return the site responding with the image data **must** include an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header set from the "origin" request header, such as

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

or the wildcard version:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to enable javascript access to the data returned.

Note `https://i.stack.imgur.com` **does not** return access control headers, so images returned from that domain will taint canvas objects. I highly recommend reading http://expressjs.com/resources/middleware/cors.html if you are are writing or modifying a node/express server to support CORS.

#### window `load` event

Wait until after the window `load` event fires to process image data. If processed earlier image loading may not be available.

---

#### Corrupt image results

The incorrect image data shown in the updated post is caused by not alligning the 3-tuples of rgb data in `pix2`  with the 4-tuples of rgba data required in `imageData.data`. To transpose the pixel data successfully try something equivalent to:

```
for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = pix2[j++];
  imgData.data[i + 1] = pix2[j++];
  imgData.data[i + 2] = pix2[j++];
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 128;  // test value
}
```

---

The following snippet creates two canvas elements: one to show the image loaded and another to show the result of canvas data manipulation. The code uses localhost servers on different ports and won't run successfully without them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>cross origin</title></head>

<body>
<h2>Image</h2>
<img id="face" crossorigin src="http://localhost:8080/share/imperial.jpg" />
<h2>Canvas</h2>
<canvas
    id="face2"
    width="112"
    height="112"
    style="border: 1px solid blue"
></canvas>

<canvas
    id="modified"
    width="112"
    height="112"
    style="border: 1px solid red"
></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
  const img = document.getElementById("face");
  const canvas = document.getElementById("face2");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  let imgData1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 112, 112)
  let pix;
  try {
    pix = imgData1.data;
  }
  catch( err) {
    console.warn( err.message);
  }

  pix = Array.from(pix);

  const pix2 = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < pix.length; i += 4) {
    pix2.push(pix[i + 0]);
    pix2.push(pix[i + 1]);
    pix2.push(pix[i + 2]);
  }

  const imgData = context.createImageData(112, 112);
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = pix2[j++];
    imgData.data[i + 1] = pix2[j++];
    imgData.data[i + 2] = pix2[j++];
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 128; // test value
  }
 
  const canvas2 = document.getElementById("modified");
  const context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  context2.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);

});
</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my question with the current error, do you know why that is happening? thanks for the previous response.

Comment: Sorry about the delay - writing an image server with cross origin support took the longest :)  A bug in the code copying `rgb` data to `rgba` data buffers which is easily fixed - see the updated answer for details.

Comment: Thansk for you effort, I will check latter this response but looks ok.